# What does the percent mean with an equals and not a like?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I'm learning mysql and I stumbled upon this syntax:

```
SELECT vaule FROM table WHERE field1='%s' AND field2 = 1
```

what is the meaning of `%s`?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to the SQL server.  It is almost certainly evaluated by whatever language/tools you are using before it was sent to the server.

Comment: The query is retrieving all rows where `field1` contains the value `'%s'`. Because the `LIKE` operator is not used, the `%` sign does not have any special meaning

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `s/contains/is equal to/`.

Comment: @glglgl: yes, that's what I meant ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This %s is a placeholder which can be filled e.g. with the `sprintf` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function.
Anyway, prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) would be a better idea.

Comment: How do you know Paul is using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

`%` is a placeholder, but it only works with `like`

```
SELECT vaule FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%s'
```

That query would return all records where `field1` ends with `s`.